# Jersey xml application does not work . HTTP 500 Internal Server

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, glassfish

I'm learning webservice but I want to show List elements . I was using MediaType.APPLICATION_XML for return type.But I taked a error 500 Internal server error . When I used APPLICATION_JSON of instead APPLICATION_XML , no problem but I do not know error is occuring.Why ?

I am using jdk 13 and tomcat 8 sometimes 9. StaffInformation.java

StaffInformation.java

```
   package com.webservices.Last;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class StaffInformation {
    
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    public StaffInformation(String name, String surname) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public StaffInformation() {
        super();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    }
```

EmployeesList.java

```
  package com.webservices.Last;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path(value = "employee")
public class EmployeesList {

    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/takemployee")
    public List<StaffInformation> Staffexplanation()
    {
        List<StaffInformation> st = new ArrayList<>();
        StaffInformation sI = new StaffInformation("Kerem", "Kagan");
        st.add(sI);
        return st;
    }       
}
```

Last/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.webservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>Last</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Last</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>Last</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.31</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  
  </welcome-file-list>
  
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.webservices.Last</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[My Project Files below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk8Ad.png)

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need proper xml generator. you shall add something like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not work again. I added your guess , then I added version 2.31 it did not work again